# Linq to SQL and Intersect

Tags: linq-to-sql, intersect

Folks,

I need to use Intersect on a LINQ to SQL query.  However, I get an exception basically stating that I can't.

The code compiles fine, but LINQ to SQL gets angry.

Is there any way to replicate Intersect with LINQ to SQL?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the exception and the exact query?

Comment: It is definitely possible. See this example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399392.aspx

Comment: Sorry, I wrote this question up in WAY too much of a hurry.  I'll get the exact exception later.  I saw you article down below, and it sure does look like I should be able to use Intersect...weird.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of how to do this:

```
var coolColors = (from pen in mydb.Pens select pen.Color).Intersect
        (from pencil in mydb.Pencils select pencil.Color);
```

Answer (score 0):

`var example = memoryObject.Union(sqlObject)`is not allowed
but you can do
`var example = sqlOjbect.Union(memoryObject)` if both sqlObject and memoryObject are of the same type.