# How to convert my sql query to linq query

Tags: mysql, sql, linq, t-sql, linq-to-sql

Hi i write this sql query but i want to write linq version
sql version

```
Select CalisanId From Calisanlar Where Lisans=0 INTERSECT (Select CalisanId From Covids)
```

```
  

        public List<LisansCovid> GetLisansCovid()
            {
                using (SirketDBContext context = new SirketDBContext())
                {
                    var result =
        (from cal1 in context.Calisanlar
         where cal1.Lisans == 0
         select cal1.CalisanId)
        .Intersect
            (from cal2 in context.Covids
             select cal2.CalisanId);
    
     //exception              return result.ToList();        
            }}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linq to SQL and Intersect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937693/linq-to-sql-and-intersect)

Comment: no. i'm sorry :(

Comment: Why not? It is the equivalent function.

Comment: Can you convert my sql query to linq ?

Comment: What have you attempted so far? Can you show us.

Comment: What LINQ are you using: LINQ to Objects / SQL / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x / 6.x? What database provider?

Comment: i develop web app on visual studio 2019 and i want to display sql query on swagger ui @NetMage

Comment: What is the exception that you are getting

Comment: ArgumentNullException

Comment: Sample data and the data structures you are using would be a big help. The error message is saying that the query is returning null, hence the `ToList()` fails.

Comment: very thanks @PeterSmith :)) can you also look at this problem ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70402378/how-to-this-sql-queries-convert-to-linq

Comment: I'm not a code writing factory. Stack Overflow is here to help with diagnosing and solving problems; to assist with learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following, not tested; assumes a database connection `db`:

```
var infoQuery =
    (from cal1 in db.Calisanlar
    where cal1.Lisans == 0
    select cal1.CalisanId)
    .Intersect
        (from cal2 in db.Covids
        select cal2.CalisanId);
var result = inforQuery?.ToList() ?? 0;
```

or, lambda expression

```
var infoQuery = 
    (db.Calisanlar.Where(x => x.Lisans == 0).Select(x => x.CalisanId))
    .Instersect(db.Covids.Select(x => x.CalisanId))
```

UPDATE
Assuming `CalisanID` is an `integer`  checks for `null` return and returns zero if found. Again, not tested.

Comment: firstly thanks but i didn't work when i write return infoQuery.ToList();. I edited my code. you can see

Comment: Answer updated to allow for null return. However, still need sample data to know why the query is returning a null.